# Skype for Business Online - Send and Receive message using UCWA

Tags: bots, lync, skype-for-business, ucwa

I am trying to build a BOT like service for "Skype For Business".
As of now Microsoft BOT Framework doesn't have out of the box channel for this.
Searching in the internet, I found following nice workaround to tackel such problem Using Lync Server 2013 SDK.
http://devopssnippets.blogspot.jp/2016/08/integrating-lyncskype-for-business-with.html#.WIW3PXKtTjE

But in my case, I have "**Skype For Business Online**" in Office365 where Lync Server 2013 SDK is not supported.

**UCWA** web API seems to be available for "**Skype For Business Online**". 
Using this API, I want to receive IM and forward this to my existing BOT by using **DirectLine API**.
And finally I want to reply the skype user with the response from the DirectLine API.

So, here what I am curious to know that whether it is possible to receive message from user and send message to user by using UCWA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to send and receive messages using UCWA API if you are using Skype For Business. You can implement the UCWA API and then whenever you receive any message, you can forward them to the bot. And after you receive a message back from your bot, you can forward that to the user.

Here are some links that might be of help.

[Setting up Skype for Business Online using Skype WebSDK](http://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2016/03/skype-web-sdk-online-setting-everything-up-step-by-step-guide/)

[Skype For Business Step By Step](http://www.thoughtstuff.co.uk/skype-web-sdk/)

[Official UCWA site with examples and steps](https://ucwa.skype.com/websdk#)

Comment: @rku0526 My pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

Skype and Skype for Business are 2 completely different things. You won't be able to connect Skype and Skype Bots (Microsoft Bots) with UCWA or Skype for Business Online

Comment: Thanks for the response. My questions was not much clear. I have rephrased the questions to clarify what I am trying to achieve.